# Custom hovering in Xtext 2.10

Tags: eclipse, hover, xtext

I use `Xtext 2.10.0.v201605250459` with `Eclipse Neon 4.6.1` and want to implement custom hover texts like described in [this tutorial](https://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/07/16/hover-support-in-xtext-2-0-tutorial/). However it does not work (no custom text appears as expected, but the default one as handled by Xtext framework).

My implementation of the hover provider:

```
package demo.ui.hover

import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.hover.html.DefaultEObjectHoverProvider
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject

class DemoEObjectHoverProvider extends DefaultEObjectHoverProvider
{
   override protected getFirstLine(EObject o)
   {
        return "This is some demo text!"
   }
}
```

Here is how I register it:

```
/*
 * generated by Xtext 2.10.0
 */
package demo.ui

import org.eclipse.xtend.lib.annotations.FinalFieldsConstructor
import demo.ui.hover.DemoEObjectHoverProvider

/**
 * Use this class to register components to be used within the Eclipse IDE.
*/
@FinalFieldsConstructor
class DemoUiModule extends AbstractDemoUiModule
{
   def bindIEObjectHoverProvider()
   {
      typeof(DemoEObjectHoverProvider)
   }
}
```

Can you identify some error there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your guice binding is wrong

```
def Class<? extends IEObjectHoverProvider> bindIEObjectHoverProvider() {
    DemoEObjectHoverProvider
}
```

see https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/302_configuration.html#dependency-injection for the conventions

Comment: Right, this was the issue. I thought, it will automatically be figured out by type deduction, but apparently not.